# Email a content with Link using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, jsonp

I have an html form having input fields to add a new user. Once a user is added to my database  the mail is sent to her/him using the sendmail() function in my adduser.js file. The mail sent as per my standard.But the thing is i want to add a hyperlink in to the body content.
My line is like this:

```
  sendMail(result.email, DbConfig.mailConfig.subject, "Dear" + " " + req.body.txtFirstName + req.body.txtLastName + ",\n Welcome to, COMPANY NAME " + txt.link('http://www.website.in') + "Your Login details are below: \n User name:" + req.body.txtLoginId + " \n Password:" + result.pwd)
```

But it is not working as i expected. The result in my mail is

```
Dear user.
Welcome to,COMPANY NAME<ahref="www.website.in"></a>.
```

It is coming like this.But the link redirects to a specified target. My expectation is:

```
Dear user.
Welcome to,COMPANY NAME.(on click of company name it redirects to targeted link).
```

How can i achieve this.I try to use directly  tag in my JS. It also nt works properly in my case.

Thanks,

Comment: There's no way javascript can send an email like this... you probably are using PhP ?

Comment: you cann't send email using javascript, you need to use some server side technologies like php/java

Comment: am using node and i have a json file

Comment: I receive mail in my inbox when i add my name in my form.

Comment: You will need to specify HTML format in your mail headers.

Comment: If you're using node.js then you might want to consider using https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates for the email templates.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up plain text and html (you're using \n for new lines, but then inserting <a> elements for links)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments

Comment: Oh and of course, it is generally an awful idea to email passwords especially as most people reuse them. The standard practice is to save a 'salt' and a 'hash' value for each user. This lets you check their passwords are good without storing the actual passwords.

Answer (score 0):

One way is [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) on node. I have taken the liberty of pasting their example:

```
$ npm install emails;
//app.js:
var email   = require("./path/to/emailjs/email");
var server  = email.server.connect({
   user:    "username", 
   password:"password", 
   host:    "smtp.gmail.com", 
   ssl:     true
});

var message = {
   text:    "i hope this works", 
   from:    "you <username@gmail.com>", 
   to:      "someone <someone@gmail.com>, another <another@gmail.com>",
   cc:      "else <else@gmail.com>",
   subject: "testing emailjs",
   attachment: 
   [
      {data:"<html>i <i>hope</i> this works!</html>", alternative:true},
      {path:"path/to/file.zip", type:"application/zip", name:"renamed.zip"}
   ]
};

// send the message and get a callback with an error or details of the message that was sent
server.send(message, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });

// you can continue to send more messages with successive calls to 'server.send', 
// they will be queued on the same smtp connection

// or you can create a new server connection with 'email.server.connect' 
// to asynchronously send individual emails instead of a queue
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the sendMail function is working correctly, you'll need to specify the "content type" of the email in the headers. I'm unfamiliar the particular function that you're using but PHP's 'mail' function is formatted similarly and takes a fourth parameter for additional headers.

I imagine it might work something like:

```
var headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' + "\r\n";
var message = "Dear" + " " + req.body.txtFirstName + req.body.txtLastName + ",\n Welcome to, COMPANY NAME " + txt.link('http://www.website.in') + "Your Login details are below: \n User name:" + req.body.txtLoginId + " \n Password:" + result.pwd;

sendMail(result.email, DbConfig.mailConfig.subject, message, headers)
```